# Linearization and Discretization of a Non Linear System

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system

I'm studying Model Predictive Control, and basically, the most solid theory is developed for Discrete-Time Systems. For Continuous Non-Linear System is advised to linearize the system at a point of equilibrium and then discretize it or directly discretize the system and use discrete model predictive control theory, depending on the applications.

I would like to know more about how can be safe that the outputs we get with the discretized system coherent with the result we get with the continuous nonlinear system.

Particularly, I have the following questions.
I know that for linear systems the can have an exact discretization with Euler Discretization, so $x_d(0) = x_c(t=0)$, $x_d(1) = x_c(T)$ and so on, where $x_d$ is the discrete state, $x_c$ the continuous state and T the sample time.  Still, what guarantees we have on points between the sample time, so between (0 and T, T and 2T, .... n*T and (n+1)*T)? How can be sure that these points are somewhat bounded?

Instead for a non-linear system, what can we conclude if we discretize the system?  And what is the most common and safe procedure to have a successful discretization on a nonlinear ODE?

Comment: You are just studying MPC and you already made up your mind about it being the most solid theory. I really recommend you not to fall this stupid classification game. There is a difference between sampling a signal (you mentioned Euler which is the typical industrial PID input discretization scheme), and discretizing a system model such as Tustin or Zero-Order hold (you can still use forward Euler but the results would require extra care). These are different things and requires a decision process. There is no fixed rule

Answer (score 2):

All digital control systems are discrete.

Sample time is chosen short enough so the system does not scape in between.

Majority of real systems tolerate noise and disturbances to an extend. So, small deviation is very normal.

Minor errors are corrected with the feedback and observation methods in the way that the error does not accumulate.

Linearization and discretization are not the same thing nor against each other. They are independent concepts.

If the system is nonlinear but [linearization](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/101108047/module7/Lecture%2016.pdf) around the nominal point works, use it. But if the system is too mucn nonlinear and simple linearization is not sufficient think about using [adaptive MPC or gain-scheduled MPC](http://fumblog.um.ac.ir/gallery/839/mpc_gs.pdf).

Comment: Beside this question, does any one have enough permission to create tags "mpc" or "model predictive control"?

Comment: Thank you for answering. So basically, as I understand, we try linearization and then we discretize for non-linear systems, then if linearization is not sufficient we use other technique as adaptive MPC. Is there any theorem that guarantees us that if we control a discretized system the analog continuous-time system will be controlled well or the only real way is to simulate the controller on the non-linear system?

Comment: @TommasoBendinelli, I am not sure what you are looking for. In the robotic applications for example, the sample time might be in the range of `10 ms`. This sample time is small enough to have a good control. If you are not happy with it reduce it to `1 ms` at the cost of higher computations. I have never seen anyone goes smaller than that. BTW, even if adaptive MPC does not work, this is not the end of the world. You can go for NMPC (Nonlinear Model Predictive Control) at the cost of its complexity.

Comment: So, for robotics application, we discretize the system on the order of 10 ms. Without going through linearization! My problem was really that I can't see linearization working outside a neighborhood of the equilibrium area, and therefore if we want to control something from point A to B I can't see how linearization can be useful. Furthermore, I was worried that discretization error could somewhat propagate for long period of time, although sample in really small chunks.

Comment: @TommasoBendinelli, I do not see it wise to use MPC for a long path planning using a small processor. What about applying a path planning such as [RRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidly-exploring_random_tree) and then apply MPC to follow this path efficiently? I agree that the system with yaw are highly nonlinear. You can apply nonlinear MPC if possible for you. An ad-hoc solution is to apply a different controller when yaw is high and when the drone direction angle reduces, then the controller switches to linear MPC.